# Is infinity even and odd at the same time?

Tags: calculus, limits

For a real number $x < -1$, what is the result of $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x^n$?

At first I thought of "$\infty$" as the solution, but that's only the case if $n$ is an even number. For an odd number it would be "$-\infty$". But here $n$ goes against "$\infty$".

My refined answer would be: The result fluctuates between "$\infty$" and "$-\infty$".

What is a good notation to write down this answer?

Comment: Are you sure you weren't asked about $0 < x < 1$ or $|x| < 1$?

Comment: I think you are making a mistake..Check for example,for $x=1/2$

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean "even" and "odd" in the sense that $2, -2, 4, -4, 6, -6, \dots$ are even and $1,-1,3,-3,5,-5, \dots$ are odd, but if so, the properties of even and odd only apply to integers (not to decimals or irrational numbers).  But even if they did apply to decimals and irrational numbers, $\infty$ is neither of these.  $\infty$ isn't a real number (which is why we express the reals as $(-\infty, \infty)$ -- open parentheses around $\infty$ since it's not included, i.e., not a real number), so it wouldn't make sense to ask if it is even or odd.

Comment: For example, we know donuts can come with a filling or not.  So it makes sense to ask the donut shop if the donut is filled or not.  But does it make sense to ask the shop if the tree outside of the shop is filled?  Of course not.  You can ask the question, sure, but in the context, the question doesn't really belong there.

Comment: It was my mistake, I wanted x < -1, of course. Sorry!

Comment: There isn't great notation. But you can say the *limit points* of the sequence are $\infty$ and $-\infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: asking if infinity is even or odd is as absurd as asking if a shoe is prime or composite. In other words: infinity is not an integer number at all. Hence is not even or odd.

Second: the limit you are asking about is $\infty$ if $x>1$, $1$ if $x=1$ and $0$ if $-1< x<1$. Otherwise, the sequence "oscillates" and does not have a limit.

Comment: Thanks for the word "oscillates". The function oscillates, say for x=-3 (and n against infinity). So, that's the reason for why it has no limit?